# Excel - Determine if value is contain in named range

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet that I used to track if members have required training at specific levels

A:1 - Name
B:1 - Submission status
C:1 - Certificate obtained
D:1 - Required Certificate level
E:1 - Compliance Status

B - Can be awaiting or submitted 
C - Name of the certificate
D - There are 14 required certificate levels and each contains several certificates that a member can obtain (placed in named ranges on another sheet)
E - Will be one of a few options: Compliant, Non-Compliant; needs submission, or Compliant; does not meet required level

I would like a formula or VB that can determine if the member's certificate meets the requirement of the level for the position they occupy.  If a member has the certificate or one of a higher level then they are compliant.

ie:  Level I certs include: CERT A & CERT B/Level II certs include: CERT B, CERT C, CERT D

Member Jane Doe occupies a level I position and he has obtained CERT C, so she would be compliant.

Member John Doe occupies a level II position and he has obtained CERT A, so he would not be compliant because his position requires a higher level certification

Comment: What have you tried so far? SO isn't for giving out answers but rather assisting with them

Comment: I'm not too good with VB but for formulas I can't get the cells to = "named range"

Comment: I've used this formula to go through one list but i'd have to manually type the name of the range each time =IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(B5=named range))>0, "Compliant", "Non-Compliant".  I want the formula or code to determine which range to start parsing through based on the required level first then move through the remaining higher levels until it finds a match or it returns a false

Comment: Instead of using individual named ranges, why not just create a lookup table with the first column being the certificate names and the second column being the certificate level, and then you could just do a VLOOKUP on the "Certificate Obtained" to determine the level of the cert, and compare that to the "Required Certificate Level" to get your output.

Comment: @tigeravatar how would I go about tying the certificate to its appropriate level?

Comment: @m.skinner See answer

Answer (score 0):

Let's pretend you have a data setup like this:

[image]

Columns I and J are the lookup table for the certs and their respective cert levels.  So to get the cert level based on the certificate obtained, which in this case is column D, I used this formula in cell D2 and copied down:

```
=VLOOKUP(C2,I:J,2,FALSE)
```

Then it's just a matter of comparing the cert level based on that VLOOKUP to the Required Cert Level shown in column E.  Here is the formula in column F to show "Non-Compliant" or "Compliant".  I put this in cell F2 and copied down:

```
=IF(D2>=E2,"Compliant","Non-Compliant")
```

Comment: That works great!  I have two additional questions:  If a certificate is in multiple categories how would I do that?  And some certifications in a higher level can cover the requirement for a lower level.  ie:  I have Cert C, which is a Level 2 cert but my position only requires me to have a Level 1 cert.  How would I cover this? Is it possible?

Comment: any thoughts on how to work this if a certificate is in multiple categories?

Comment: @m.skinner If a cert is in multiple categories, put it in the lookup table multiple times in descending order (highest category first, then next highest, etc).  That way the VLOOKUP will return the highest category, which is all we really care about to verify if the user is Compliant or not.  Is there some reason you would need it to return something other than the cert's highest category?

Comment: The cert levels are hierarchical, however, within a category -.  For instance, Cert Levels 1,2,3 are in Category 1, Cert Levels 4,5,6 are in Category 2, and some cert levels are just standalone. A Cert in Level 6 (category 2) can satisfy the requirements for a lower 5 or 4 position but does not cover certs in category 1 or any other standalone category.  Let me know if this is confusing at all.

Comment: @m.skinner This description is different enough from your original post that you'll need to create a new question. Please provide representative sample data and expected results.